# Windows 11 Issues

Tags: windows

I received my computer in 2012. It is a 'hp ProBook 4530s'. After doing the PC health check, I was told that my computer did not reach the minimum requirements, so I could not upgrade or install Windows 11. At this present moment, I am running Windows 10. My main questions are, 'Is this computer too old to receive Windows 11, and would I have to buy a new one if I wanted to upgrade? If not, how do I go about fixing this problem, or would I have to wait to Microsoft correct the problem?

Comment: It's not even qualified to run Win10. MS have relaxed restrictions on Win11 - but you can't do it via Windows Update & you do it at your own risk.

Comment: It is much too old to qualify for Windows 11. You need to replace it with a newer machine.

Comment: @John - You don't - you just need to accept the risk it won't work properly. See https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-will-run-on-old-pcs/ & a myriad other similar articles.

Comment: I have a newer machine than the OP (Lenovo) and it does not qualify. That is why I said newer machine to run Windows 11.  I have Windows 11 Preview Release on the older machine but it will not run Production Windows 11.

Comment: Win11 has been out about an hour & a half, metaphorically speaking. Wait a couple of months & see what happens. Frankly, anyone jumping right in as an early adopter needs to be more fully aware of the dangers in what is really untested software. The wise money is on waiting 6 months or so.